# Java 8 Type Inference - How reduction is done for generic constructors?

Tags: java, java-8, type-inference, language-specifications

I was reading the java 8 language specification type inference. It says that

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>()
```

would be first reduced

```
ArrayList<α> -> List<String>
```

and then to

```
α <= String
```

and at the end to

```
α = String
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how the reduction of the constraint

```
ArrayList<α> -> List<String> to α <= String
```

was derived. It would be a great help if anyone can point out the logic using the java 8 language spec.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.2) the link to the reduction

---

Thanks [#Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for the explanation. Following is my take on the derivation of

```
new ArrayList<> -> List<String> to ArrayList<α> -> List<String>
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

First to find the temporary method for the constructor we use [#15.9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3)

> - Otherwise, the arguments to the constructor are the arguments in the argument list of the class instance creation expression, if any,
>     in the order they appear in the expression.
> - If the class instance creation expression uses <> to elide class type
>     arguments, a list of methods m1...mn is defined for the purpose of
>     overload resolution and type argument inference.

Then [#18.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2) is used to derive

```
ArrayList<α> -> List<String>
```

Because of being a poly expression and not having any wild card type parameters;

> - Otherwise, the constraint formula ‹R θ → T› is reduced and incorporated with B2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m glad you didn’t ask how to come from `new ArrayList<>() → List<String>` to `ArrayList<α> → List<String>` as, while looking obvious, per applying §18.2.1, we will find it requires a discussion of the entire §15.9.3, followed by a discussion of §18.5.2.

Proceeding from `ArrayList<α> → List<String>` is easier:

> #### [§18.2.2. Type Compatibility Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.2)
>
> A constraint formula of the form ‹S → T› is reduced as follows:
>
> - … (five inapplicable bullets omitted)
> - Otherwise, the constraint reduces to ‹S <: T›.

> #### [§18.2.3. Subtyping Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.3)
>
> A constraint formula of the form ‹S <: T› is reduced as follows:
>
> - … (five irrelevant bullets omitted)
> - Otherwise, the constraint is reduced according to the form of `T`:
>
>   - If `T` is a parameterized class or interface type, or an inner class type of a parameterized class or interface type (directly or indirectly), let A<sub>1</sub>, ..., A<sub>n</sub> be the type arguments of `T`. Among the supertypes of `S`, a corresponding class or interface type is identified, with type arguments B<sub>1</sub>, ..., B<sub>n</sub>. If no such type exists, the constraint reduces to *false*. Otherwise, the constraint reduces to the following new constraints: for all *i* (1 ≤ i ≤ n), ‹B<sub>i</sub> <= A<sub>i</sub>›..

So `ArrayList<α> → List<String>` is first reduced to `ArrayList<α> <: List<String>`, then, since `List<String>` is a parametrized interface, a corresponding super type of `ArrayList<α>` is identified, which will be `List<α>`, then, the constraint is reduced to a set of constraints for each corresponding type parameter (here we have exactly one), so we get `α <= String`.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification. I updated the question with how I think the new ArrayList<>() -> List<String> was reduced to ArrayList<alpha> -> List<String>. It would be a great help if you could check that for any misconceptions.